# text2code in python jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, docker, nlp, jupyter

I have installed text2code via docker, but it doesn't seem to run in jupyter notebook

Steps followed

1. installed Docker
2. ran this in command prompt : docker pull deepklarity/jupyter-text2code:latest
   3)run the container in docker
3. I got a URL from the container 127.0.0.1:8888/…
4. run that in the browser (at this stage the extension is installed and we are supposed to get a dialogue box in which you can start typing, Refer to the video in the Text2code on github or youtube) which is not showing up, which means the installation of the extension wasn't successful

https://github.com/deepklarity/jupyter-text2code
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gZ7_9W-TJs

Comment: What command have you used? And what error do you get? BTW maybe you will get answer faster directly by googling I guess. Maybe the kernel you are using is different than the installation place for text2code. Honestly people here are not so forgiving when complete detailed effort is not shown

Comment: Also we should be able to reproduce the error otherwise we might of little help

Comment: I am not seeing the dialogue box to write the command. there is no error message displayed

Comment: Share the list of commands you used, so that I can reproduce the error

Comment: 1) installed Docker 2) ran this in command prompt : docker pull deepklarity/jupyter-text2code:latest
3)run the container in docker 4) I got a URL from the container http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=ed48bdae4f49796b17d16a216267c756022f3b9755e72357   5) run that in the browser (at this stage the extension is installed and we are supposed to get a dialogue box in which you can start typing, Refer to the video in the Text2code on github or youtube)

Comment: https://github.com/deepklarity/jupyter-text2code

Comment: Edit the question rather than adding comment.

Comment: as I said I'm a noob at coding, so i am looking into extensions that use NLP for scripting.

Comment: Stackoverflow won't teach you how to write the code you need. Please [edit] your question to include what code you've written/tried and what errors you're getting along the way. For instance, doesn't sound like you ran `docker logs` to see what the notebook server is actually doing

Comment: If you have a specific library issue with something on Github, you should create an issue there as those are the maintainers and people that wrote the instructions

Comment: i did run the docker logs